# How do I use my Windows 10 laptop to access the printer connected to my Windows 10 desktop?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, printer, homegroup

My printer is connected via USB port to my desktop PC. A few days ago, I upgraded the desktop from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Prior to the upgrade, I had been successfully accessing my printer from my laptop through a Homegroup connection. The laptop has had Windows 10 for a couple of months, but the desktop only for the past few days. I am now no longer able to access the printer from my laptop PC. Homegroup seems to still be present on both computers, and my laptop still recognizes the main desktop as part of its network, but I cannot get the laptop to recognize the printer attached to the desktop. Causes? Solutions?

Comment: Is the printer still shared from the desktop? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/share-printer

Comment: Yes. In Homegroup, printers are one of the items shared within the Homegroup. The specific printer is not identified, but it is set as the default printer in Settings: Devices and Printers